# Filling matrix with data from two columns of dataframe

Tags: r, matrix

I am so desperated and even I am ready to lose some more rep points but I have to ask it.
(Yes, I read some threads about it).

I created a dataframe with only 2 columns I want to put to the matrix (I didn't know how to pick just 2 columns from whole data):

```
    tbl_corel <- tbl_end[,c("diff", "abund_mean")]
```

In next step I created and empty matrix:

```
## Creating a empty matrix to check the correlation between diff and abund_mean
mat_corel <- matrix(0, ncol = 2)
colnames(mat_corel) <- c("diff", "abund_mean")
```

I tried to use that function to fill the matrix with the data:

```
mat_corel <- matrix(tbl_corel), nrow = 676,ncol = 2)
```

Of course I had to check manually how many rows I have in my data frame... 
It doesn't work. 
Tried that function as well:

```
mat_corel[ as.matrix(tbl_corel) ] <- 1
```

It doesn't work. I'd be so grateful for the help.

```
  diff abund_mean
1    0 3444804.80
2    0  847887.02
3    0   93654.19
4    0  721692.76
5    0  382711.04
6    1  428656.66
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do here. You can check the correlation of 2 columns of your data frame in the data frame itself by specifying either the column names or the column indices to the cor() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a matrix from your two-columns data frame, there is a more direct and simpler way : just transform you data frame as a matrix directly :

```
mat_corel <- as.matrix(tbl_corel)
```

But if you just want to compute a correlation coefficient, you can do it directly from your data frame :

```
cor(tbl_end$diff, tbl_end$abund_mean)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's so easy to do if you ask someone. That's what I wanted. I tried "mat_corel <- matrix(tbl_corel)". Forgot about "as". I wish I could vote up your answer. Thx once again.

Comment: Not asking for rep, but do you know that even if you can't upvote an answer, you can accept it by checking the green mark on its left ? This allows for visitors to know at a glance that the question had been answered.

Comment: Already did. Trying now to plot my results using: "pdf(file="myplot.pdf", width = 10, height =13) #create new pdf
plot(diff ~ abund_mean) #see data but got this problem "Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
  object is not a matrix"

Comment: Use `plot(diff~abund_mean, data=tbl_end)`. But please don't ask questions in a comment, Open a new question if you really ned it.

Comment: Okey, in future I will make another question. I was just worried about my rep.

Comment: You gain reputation in Stackoverflow by asking questions and accepting answers to them so you don't have to worry about that.